# can't save smileys in mysql DB liferay

Tags: mysql, exception, save, liferay, portlet

I am using **liferay 6.2** with **mysql- 5.5.52**. In a custom portlet I have exposed some web services which are used by Android & ios apps, in some api their is a string parameter & if we send smiles in that param like , it throws exception: **java.sql.SQLException: Incorrect string value: '\xF0\x9F\x98\x90\xF0\x9F...' for column 'comment_' at row 1**, I have also tried changing database collation to **utf8mb4 -default collation**, in that case i am able to save this ☺, but not others, I am trying to find out what is the issue.

Answer (score 3):

As you didn't provide details on what exactly you have changed, it's hard to be sure this answer is relevant. Just in case you didn't, make sure to change the **character set** and not only the **collation**.

> A character set is a set of symbols and encodings. A collation is a set of rules for comparing characters in a character set.

Also double check your database connection string. It may enforce different encoding than the one specified for the database / table.

Comment: I have tried changing the character, also tried with changing mysql variables character_set_client, _connection, and _results to utf8mb4, but still the same issue.

Comment: now what i am doing is encoding string to base64 before saving & it gets saved, but while decoding getting a different result.

Answer (score 0):

The problem can be on any layer - most definitely something to do with encoding (as Milen describes in his answer). You might get illegally encoded (or decoded) content from your webservice, mangle it up in the database connection (client side) or have a wrong encoding in the database. Liferay's documentation only mentions `create database dbname character set utf8;` for the database.

One of the prime source of UTF-8 characters that are easy to test and spot is http://fliptitle.com - once your favorite test text comes through correctly, you likely have encoding correct. If it doesn't: Check your fonts, because either they don't have all the characters used or you've got encoding wrong somewhere.